# Azure App Service Multi-Tenant functionality Not Actually Working

Tags: azure

I followed these steps in an attempt to create an Azure App that allows login from multiple Azure AD Tenants:

---

**Create a new App Service and turn on Authentication**

1) In Azure Portal: I created a brand-new empty Azure App Service and dialed its URL up in my browser to be sure it was working properly.

2) I navigated to my new App Service, then the  "Authentication / Authorization" blade.

3) I turned On the "App Service Authentication" switch.

4) I chose "Log in with Azure Active Directory" from the "Action to take when request is not authenticated" dropdown.

5) Under "Authentication Providers" on the same blade, I clicked on "Azure Active Directory", which navigated me down to the "Azure Active Directory Settings" blade.

6) Within this blade, I selected "Express" on the "Management Mode" radio button. Selection of Active Directory was grayed-out but it was the one I wanted to use -- the current one.

---

**Create a new Azure AD App that's associated with my App Service**

7) I clicked on "Azure AD App" and it prompted me to create an Azure AD App, which by default had the same name as my App Service name, so I kept it.

8) Still on the "Azure Active Directory Settings" blade, I  clicked the "Manage Application" button under the "Manage Azure Active Directory Application" heading. I was navigated one more blade down, where the heading was the name of the Azure AD App I just created.

9) Once here, I clicked the "Settings" button, then "Properties" in the Settings blade.

10) Within "Properties" I set the "Multi-Tenanted" radio button to "Yes".

11) Also within "Properties": as is said to be required for multi-tenant to work: I also changed the "App ID URI" to something unique, and also from a Verified URL within my organization. In my case I used:

`https://<<MyTenantName>.onmicrosoft.com/login-ProofOfConcept`

---

**Test the Security Functionality**

12) With everything presumably set up, I first tried logging-in to my new application with a user that existed within my current B2C Tenant. I dialed the URL up for my App Service, I got prompted by microsoftonline to Authenticate, I authenticated, and then I got straight into my application with no problem.

---

**Here's The Problem**

13) Then, I logged-out and tried to login again -- but this time as a user that's in another Azure AD, which is just one I spun-up under my personal gmail account. I was expecting it to "just work" but after I authenticated as this other user, this error was displayed onscreen:

***AADSTS50020: User account 'MyUserName@gmail.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant '[MyTenantName]' and cannot access the application '[MyApplicationGUID]'([AzureADApplicationName]) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.***

This is precisely the behavior I was hoping to avoid by **enabling** Multi-Tenant. I was hoping that it would just "login" this user, who is the member of an existing Azure AD. Is there a configuration-step I missed?

Comment: Your application also needs to be talking to the "common" endpoint of Azure AD to allow any tenant to log in. I'd assume the App Service auth redirects you to your tenant-specific endpoint.

Comment: I thought that might be a possibility. Here is the Login URL my application forwards to by default:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[Local-B2CTenantGUID-Of-MyWebSite]/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code+id_token&redirect_uri=https://[MyWebSite-FriendlyName].azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=[ApplicationGUID-Of-MyWebSite]&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=06e5352b601c4256936d33a3ea84e605_20190511011408&state=redir=%2F`

So, I manually changed the `[Local-B2CTenantGUID-Of-MyWebSite]` part of that URL to "common". Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're maybe looking at Azure AD B2B here, whereby you need to invite the non Azure AD user first: see this [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/delegate-invitations) reference. 
Assuming you have the default settings, which is allow all users to invite non Azure AD users to access in this instance an app, invite your second user @hotmail and then try and logon, see this [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/add-users-administrator) reference. 
If you want anyone from @hotmail to be able to log into your app, consider using Azure AD B2C, see this [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory-b2c/) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. No, this is indeed B2C I am using. Any other ideas?